# How to finish the forever when another component has finished in uvm?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

How to finish the forever when another component has finished in uvm?
There is 2 components first component_a just send transaction from uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo.
and other component_b keep polling the received transaction.
I want if component_a has finished then component_b also finished.

But currently component_b never stop because it is along with forever statement.

How do I finish the another component's process? component_b never stop.

```
class basic_test extends uvm_test;
..
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);

  phase.raise_objection(this);    // raise an objection
   #500;
  phase.drop_objection(this);     // drop an objection
 endtask: run_phase

endclass


class component_a extends uvm_component;

  transaction trans;
  ...
  uvm_analysis_port#(transaction) analysis_port;
  ...

  virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
 for(int a=0; a<10; a++) begin
      trans = transaction::type_id::create("trans");
      if (!trans.randomize())
        `uvm_fatal("RNDERR", "Randomization of trans failed");
      analysis_port.write(trans);
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(), "Trans Sending....",UVM_LOW)
    end
  endtask

endclass


class component_b extends uvm_component;
  ...    
  virtual task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  ...
  forever begin
     `uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformatf(" FIFO used: %0d", analy_fifo.used()), UVM_LOW)   
      if(analy_fifo.is_empty()) begin
        `uvm_info(get_type_name(), "FIFO is Empty!!!!!",UVM_LOW)
      end
      else begin
        analy_fifo.get(trans);
      `uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf(" Printing receive trans, \n ",trans.sprint()),UVM_LOW)
      end
  end

  endtask

endclass
```

I expected that component_b working as background but I only get the printg as below

```
UVM_INFO component_b.sv(55) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b] FIFO is Empty!!!!!
UVM_INFO component_b.sv(52) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b]  FIFO used: 0
UVM_INFO component_b.sv(55) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b] FIFO is Empty!!!!!
UVM_INFO component_b.sv(52) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b]  FIFO used: 0
...
```

There is no time consume by test and component_a has no chance to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the only two components, do not call `raise/drop_objection()` in `component_b::run_phase`.

Comment: I expected that component_b working as background if I get rid of raise/drop_objection(). But it still never stop in forever loop. it just keep printing 

UVM_INFO component_b.sv(49) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b] FIFO is Empty!!!!!
UVM_INFO component_b.sv(46) @ 0: uvm_test_top.env.comp_b [component_b]  FIFO used: 0

Comment: @bu-ral I think, your `forever` has turned into an infinite loop owing to no delay in the loop!

Comment: @VineethVS https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/analysisconnections Multiple Transaction Streams With Synchronization is also no delay in the loop.

Comment: The call to get() is a blocking statement if the fifo is empty.

Comment: @dave_59 Here the get() is getting called only when the FIFO is not empty right?

Comment: @VineethVS There is no need to do that. The call to get() blocks until the FIFO is not empty.

Comment: @dave_59 Yeah, what I was asking is that, since in the example, the `get()` call won't get executed if `analy_fifo.is_empty()` returns 1. Wouldn't that result in an infinite loop?

Comment: @VineethVS I think adding delay is poor coding, what is the good way if you have to modify this code?

Answer (score -1):

Problem in component_b code is that "forever" loop is an infinite loop.
better change it as follow.add a wait.

=================================
if(analy_fifo.is_empty()) begin
`uvm_info(get_type_name(), "FIFO is Empty!!!!!",UVM_LOW) wait(analy_fifo.used >0); end else begin analy_fifo.get(trans);` uvm_info(get_type_name(),$sformatf(" Printing receive trans, \n ",trans.sprint()),UVM_LOW)
end